# How did Tobi suck in Foo using Kamui without touching him?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto Shippuden* episode 208, when Tobi fought Foo and Torune, he grabbed Torune by the shoulder and used Kamui to suck him in, but then when he sucked Foo in (at 14:14 in the episode), he didn't make contact with him.
It's been said that Tobi needs to become tangible to suck someone in because he needs to make contact. They say it in the anime and I read it on Narutopedia which I find to be right on all the time.

How did Tobi suck in Foo using Kamui without touching him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be possible since Tobi must materialize and touch his opponent in case he wants to absorb him. This is a mistake that was made by the animators. See the quote below from narutopedia:

> Occasionally, in the anime, when Tobi goes to absorb his opponent he does not touch them, this is a mistake that the animators made as in the manga there is always bodily contact. A notable occasion of this is when Tobi fights Danzō's bodyguards, he does not have any physical contact with Fū when he absorbs him.